# I'm trying to figure out simple list encryption in Python

Tags: python

So, I have to simulate some sort of encryption protocol. For example, I have list 
Hey=['Z','A']
I then transform that list into ascii list using ord() command. No big deal. Problem is here. In order to encrypt I enter some shift value that will move the ascii value and then reform it back to a letter. It's all supposed to be capital letters ranging from A to Z, so ascii code ranges from 65 to 90. I've modified shift value, so that even if it's bigger than 26 it's still works fine. However, how do I modify ascii list itself, so that if one element of a list is bigger than 90 it shifts back?
I've tried this:

```
num=[ord(i)+shift for i in hey]
if num[i]>90:
   num[i]=num[i]-26
```

However, shift will happen only if both (or all) elements of a list are bigger than 90. Is there a way to make that condition affect each element separately? So that if ascii value of one element is bigger than 90 then shift will happen, but another value will be unaffected until it becomes bigger than 90.

Answer (score 2):

I think using the modulo operator `%` would be better here. This gets the remainder of a division.

Examples:

```
>>> 10 % 5
0
>>> 10 % 2
0
>>> 10 % 3
1
>>> 10 % 6
4
```

Using this, you could replace your code with this:

```
num = [(ord(i) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65 for i in hey]
```

This also works with large values of shift. Subtracting 26 means that you can still go out of range when `shift >= 27`.

Comment: thats essentially what I was getting at ... with my addendum at the end :P (+1)

Answer (score 1):

```
num=[(ord(i)+shift) if ord(i) + shift <= 90 else (ord(i)+shift - 26) for i in hey]
```

although I think theres something wrong with your else ... you should probably wrap around to the begining of the ascii set

Comment: @user2961792 If this answer helped you it would be good to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.